# URL Rewrite Module IIS 7 redirect for urls with colon not working

Tags: iis, redirect, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect the content of an old website to a new website using IIS. My rewrite map looks like this:

```
<rewriteMaps>
  <rewriteMap name="Redirects">
<add key="/q/R.208-9899.aspx" value="/bla/garden/childrens-gardening/cat3376588.cat"/>
<add key="/store/dvd/lego-the-adventures-of-clutch-powers/8%3a939022" value="/bla/entertainment-books/dvd/cat12590010.cat" />
<add key="/store/dvd/world-steam-today--north-central-and-south-america/8:470831" value="/bla/entertainment-books/dvd/cat12590010.cat" />
</rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
```

and my `web.config` looks like this:

```
<rule name="Redirect rule1 for Redirects" enabled="true">
    <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{Redirects:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
     </rule>
```

The first url works fine but the second two fail to work.

Any pointers would be useful.

Comment: See my question/answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33136282/url-rewrite-and-custom-error-message